# EmberJS: model not initialized with data (ember-data)

Tags: model, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to load some JSON from the backend and initiate a model. So far, I think I get the model, but without its properties set :(

Here is my test code:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('person', { path: '/people/:person_id' });
});

App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: '~user1/embertest'
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
   revision: 11,
   adapter: App.Adapter,
});

var attr = DS.attr;
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
   firstName: attr('string'),
   lastName: attr('string')
});

App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
      return App.Person.find(params) ;
   }
});

App.PersonController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   contentDidChange: function() {
      debugger ;
      console.info(this.get('content'));
   }.observes('content.isLoaded')
}) ;
```

And the data is loaded from a json file which only contains:

```
{"persons": {"firstName": "Jeff","lastName": "Atwood"}}
```

Now, with the url localhost/~user/embertest.html#people/10 I see that the data gets loaded and the controller method **contentDidChange** gets called. But when I do

```
this.content.get("firstName") ; // or this.get("content").get("firstName")
```

it returns "undefined". What is going wrong here ?

Finally, here are my templates which are in the :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
    Person: {{content.firstName}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Cheers

Comment: Your JSON root should just be "person" not "persons"

Comment: If I do that I get the following error msg in my console:  Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key person but you have no mapping for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove the PersonRoute, the default model hook should be fine. I think what's going on here is that App.Person.find(params) send a findQuery() instead of a find(id).

Comment: If I remove that route, I get more or less the same result, except that the root element of the json has to be "person" and that this.content.get("firstName") returns now null instead of "undefined"

Comment: I think you must also have an id in the returned json.

Comment: I just realize your PersonController is a Controller, not an ObjectController. Change that too. Note, it's quite difficult to efficiently help you here. A whole example would be more helpul :) (jsfiddle or jsbin)

Comment: How do you fake the url in jsfiddle ? Here I've created a jsfiddle, but because of the url it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/yPzf7/3/

Comment: Some pbs with jsfiddle here. I have an other catch, in the json, the attributes must be undescored version of the models. For example it should be first_name: 'jeff'

Comment: thanks, thats it!!! the model property is "firstName" and in the json should be "first_name", I don't see why they do this!? probably to confuse people like_me :)

Comment: btw, is this bug with App.Person.find(params) reported or should I do this ?

Comment: This is all about conventions. Ember data RESTAdapter is compatible with ActiveModelSerializer out of the box. If you use a rails backend, I really encourage you to use it.
Concerning App.Person.find(), it behaves just differently depending on the parameters. If you pass nothing  it causes a GET to /persons and return an array, if you pass an id, it causes a GET to person/42, if you pass a hash, it causes a query, with this hash as the request parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the JSON is incorrect.

```
{"persons": {"firstName": "Jeff","lastName": "Atwood"}}
```

The root element should be "person" when doing a App.Person.find(params.person_id)

```
{"person": {"firstName": "Jeff","lastName": "Atwood"}}
```

I also don't believe you need the PersonRoute either because by default the route should be doing:

```
App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Person.find(params.person_id) ;
  }
});
```

When your dynamic path segment has a "*_id" in it.

Comment: I have removed it, and changed "persons" to "person". See my comment on the other post. The result is still an empty model!